# Linux copying selected files from directories and naming them after the directory name

Tags: linux, file, find, copying, cp

lets say I have  (linux/unix)

```
/directory/1/file.wmv
/directory/2/file.wmv
/directory/3/file.wmv
```

I want to copy these .wmv files into a **single** directory /example/ with files named after directory names they were in like so 1.wmv, 2.wmv, 3.wmv,

Comment: What should happen if you have 2 files with same extension (.wmv) in the same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    cp /directory/$i/file.wmv /example/$i.wmv
done
```

Comment: You could replace `{1..10}` with `$(seq 10)`, which is more portable